# Doctrine - Why is orm::schema-tool only working for some entities but not others

Tags: php, entity-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

I installed Doctrine and am using it to connect to an sqlite database. When I run `vendor/bin/doctrine  orm:schema-tool:create`, it creates new database tables for "some" of the entities in my Entity folder.

Going in the opposite direction, this command worked:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping -f --from-database annotation Entity/
```

it created new entity files in the Entity directory from new database tables in the SQLite database. But now there is one entity in my Entity folder, that orm::schema-tool is ignoring. And in fact, it looks like its only processing one file, and ignoring the rest. Heres the files in my entity folder:
[image]

And it looks like its only processing the Article.php entity file. Heres what happens when I update the schema:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi> vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --    force --dump-sql
DROP INDEX IDX_149CA72E7294869C;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __temp__ArticleAttribute AS SELECT article_id,     attribute, value FROM ArticleAttribute;
DROP TABLE ArticleAttribute;
CREATE TABLE ArticleAttribute (article_id INTEGER NOT NULL, attribute         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY, value VARCHA
R(255) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY, PRIMARY KEY(article_id, attribute),     CONSTRAINT FK_149CA72E7294869C FOREIGN KEY (article_
id) REFERENCES Article (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE);
INSERT INTO ArticleAttribute (article_id, attribute, value) SELECT     article_id, attribute, value FROM __temp__ArticleAttribute;
DROP TABLE __temp__ArticleAttribute;
CREATE INDEX IDX_149CA72E7294869C ON ArticleAttribute (article_id);

Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "7" queries were executed
```

I tried running this:

```
orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true" Entity/
```

and it basically only processes the Articles file (which has 2 entities in it), and creates an entity file for each in a new subdirectory: `Application/Mode`

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi> vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true" Entity/
Processing entity "Application\Model\Article"
Processing entity "Application\Model\ArticleAttribute"

Entity classes generated to "C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi\Entity"
```

[image]

When I run orm::info, heres what it says:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi> vendor/bin/doctrine orm:info
Found 2 mapped entities:
[OK]   Application\Model\Article
[OK]   Application\Model\ArticleAttribute
```

It still says this even after I deleted that Application directory, I don't know whats going on there.`orm:clear-cache:metadata` and also ran both of the other clear-cache commands (results and query), but it orm::info still lists those two entities as the only entities found. Where is it getting this information from? Sorry for sidetracking there, the main question I'm wondering is why the orm tools are ignoring all of the other entities in the folder.

Heres whats in this **Article.php** file:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Model;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Article
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleAttribute", mappedBy="article", cascade={"ALL"}, indexBy="attribute")
     */
    private $attributes;

    public function addAttribute($name, $value)
    {
        $this->attributes[$name] = new ArticleAttribute($name, $value, $this);
    }
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class ArticleAttribute
{
    /** @Id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="attributes") */
    private $article;

    /** @Id @Column(type="string") */
    private $attribute;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $value;

    public function __construct($name, $value, $article)
    {
        $this->attribute = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
       $this->article = $article;
    }
}
```

And heres one of the files (Progress.php) its ignoring (no database table gets created):
http://pastebin.com/hurz6cTi

Heres whats in my **bootstrap.php** file:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup,
    Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\ConfiguraDoctrine\ORM\Tools\Setuption,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSqlLogger,
    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";


// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;

$paths = array("./Entity");
$db_path = 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\spider\\chebi\\chebi.db';

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'dbname'   => 'chebi',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/chebi.db',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

**UPDATE:** I just tested out an entity file from the Doctrine: Getting Started page, I created Bug.php and ran the create command, and it worked:
[image]

So this entity file works:

http://pastebin.com/L2zum1Z7

but this one doesn't:

http://pastebin.com/hurz6cTi

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi> vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true" Entity/
Processing entity "Application\Model\Article"
Processing entity "Application\Model\ArticleAttribute"
Processing entity "Bug"
```

heres what the info says:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi> vendor/bin/doctrine orm:info
Found 3 mapped entities:
[OK]   Application\Model\Article
[OK]   Application\Model\ArticleAttribute
[OK]   Bug
```

None of my other entity files get processed. Besides Progress.php, all of my other entity files, I generated them from database schema using:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping -f --from-database annotation Entity/
```

heres an example: 
http://pastebin.com/Mn96JxQT

I don't know whats going on. Is there a way to validate Entity files to see if its in the right format?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any yaml or xml mapping files (perhaps created from running generate-entities before). If you find any then delete them.  They will interfere with the annotations.

Comment: Don't you have to configure Doctrine to use XML or YAML mapping files? For example, adding this: `$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);` to bootstrap.php makes doctrine search the config/xml folder for XML mapping files. But either way, I have no YAML or XML mapping files for these entities its ignoring.

Comment: Look carefully at the pastebin's you posted.  @Entity vs @ORM\Entity.  Possibly an autoloader issue?

Comment: Are these namespace assignments? I think the @ORM\Entity was added by the orm::convert-mapping command when I generated entity files from database schema. So maybe doctrine is only searching the \Entity namespace for entities? The Article class only has `@Entity` at the top, while the other classes I got have table declarations: `@ORM\Table(name="progress")`

Comment: The @ORM\Entity stuff comes from the Symfony framework Doctrine wrapper.  @Entity is what Doctrine uses out of the box.  It's easy to confuse the two.  The table flag just allows you to set the table name instead of using the default.